# プログラムは実行できるがTypedocがエラーになる原因が知りたい。

Tags: typescript

###### 質問内容

提示コードのコメント部内部の`A,b`部ですが`Typedoc Error` 部のようなエラーが大量に発生します。
これはどうやってエラーを解消したらいいのでしょうか？実行自体はできるのですが。`Typedoc`によるエラーが発生してしまいドキュメントが作成できません。

###### 現状

1,実行可能
2,ドキュメント作成のためtypedocが提示のようなエラーになります。(一部抜粋)
3,tsconfig.jsonは生成してから触っていません

###### コード内容

WebGLを使って立方体を描画

###### 調べたこと

TypeScript型: https://qiita.com/uhyo/items/e2fdef2d3236b9bfe74a
any型について: https://typescriptbook.jp/reference/values-types-variables/any

###### 環境

OS: windows 10
言語: TypeScript
利用ライブラリ: WebGL2
その他: node.js

###### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */
    // "incremental": true,                              /* Save .tsbuildinfo files to allow for incremental compilation of projects. */
    // "composite": true,                                /* Enable constraints that allow a TypeScript project to be used with project references. */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./.tsbuildinfo",              /* Specify the path to .tsbuildinfo incremental compilation file. */
    // "disableSourceOfProjectReferenceRedirect": true,  /* Disable preferring source files instead of declaration files when referencing composite projects. */
    // "disableSolutionSearching": true,                 /* Opt a project out of multi-project reference checking when editing. */
    // "disableReferencedProjectLoad": true,             /* Reduce the number of projects loaded automatically by TypeScript. */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2016",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    // "lib": [],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                                /* Specify what JSX code is generated. */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,                   /* Enable experimental support for legacy experimental decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    /* Emit design-type metadata for decorated declarations in source files. */
    // "jsxFactory": "",                                 /* Specify the JSX factory function used when targeting React JSX emit, e.g. 'React.createElement' or 'h'. */
    // "jsxFragmentFactory": "",                         /* Specify the JSX Fragment reference used for fragments when targeting React JSX emit e.g. 'React.Fragment' or 'Fragment'. */
    // "jsxImportSource": "",                            /* Specify module specifier used to import the JSX factory functions when using 'jsx: react-jsx*'. */
    // "reactNamespace": "",                             /* Specify the object invoked for 'createElement'. This only applies when targeting 'react' JSX emit. */
    // "noLib": true,                                    /* Disable including any library files, including the default lib.d.ts. */
    // "useDefineForClassFields": true,                  /* Emit ECMAScript-standard-compliant class fields. */
    // "moduleDetection": "auto",                        /* Control what method is used to detect module-format JS files. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "commonjs",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                                  /* Specify the root folder within your source files. */
    // "moduleResolution": "node10",                     /* Specify how TypeScript looks up a file from a given module specifier. */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                                  /* Specify the base directory to resolve non-relative module names. */
    // "paths": {},                                      /* Specify a set of entries that re-map imports to additional lookup locations. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                                   /* Allow multiple folders to be treated as one when resolving modules. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                                  /* Specify multiple folders that act like './node_modules/@types'. */
    // "types": [],                                      /* Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,                     /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */
    // "moduleSuffixes": [],                             /* List of file name suffixes to search when resolving a module. */
    // "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,               /* Allow imports to include TypeScript file extensions. Requires '--moduleResolution bundler' and either '--noEmit' or '--emitDeclarationOnly' to be set. */
    // "resolvePackageJsonExports": true,                /* Use the package.json 'exports' field when resolving package imports. */
    // "resolvePackageJsonImports": true,                /* Use the package.json 'imports' field when resolving imports. */
    // "customConditions": [],                           /* Conditions to set in addition to the resolver-specific defaults when resolving imports. */
    // "resolveJsonModule": true,                        /* Enable importing .json files. */
    // "allowArbitraryExtensions": true,                 /* Enable importing files with any extension, provided a declaration file is present. */
    // "noResolve": true,                                /* Disallow 'import's, 'require's or '<reference>'s from expanding the number of files TypeScript should add to a project. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    // "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    // "checkJs": true,                                  /* Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files. */
    // "maxNodeModuleJsDepth": 1,                        /* Specify the maximum folder depth used for checking JavaScript files from 'node_modules'. Only applicable with 'allowJs'. */

    /* Emit */
    // "declaration": true,                              /* Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                           /* Create sourcemaps for d.ts files. */
    // "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                      /* Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "outFile": "./",                                  /* Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output. */
    // "outDir": "./",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */
    // "removeComments": true,                           /* Disable emitting comments. */
    // "noEmit": true,                                   /* Disable emitting files from a compilation. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                            /* Allow importing helper functions from tslib once per project, instead of including them per-file. */
    // "importsNotUsedAsValues": "remove",               /* Specify emit/checking behavior for imports that are only used for types. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,                       /* Emit more compliant, but verbose and less performant JavaScript for iteration. */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                                 /* Specify the root path for debuggers to find the reference source code. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
    // "emitBOM": true,                                  /* Emit a UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the beginning of output files. */
    // "newLine": "crlf",                                /* Set the newline character for emitting files. */
    // "stripInternal": true,                            /* Disable emitting declarations that have '@internal' in their JSDoc comments. */
    // "noEmitHelpers": true,                            /* Disable generating custom helper functions like '__extends' in compiled output. */
    // "noEmitOnError": true,                            /* Disable emitting files if any type checking errors are reported. */
    // "preserveConstEnums": true,                       /* Disable erasing 'const enum' declarations in generated code. */
    // "declarationDir": "./",                           /* Specify the output directory for generated declaration files. */
    // "preserveValueImports": true,                     /* Preserve unused imported values in the JavaScript output that would otherwise be removed. */

    /* Interop Constraints */
    // "isolatedModules": true,                          /* Ensure that each file can be safely transpiled without relying on other imports. */
    // "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,                     /* Do not transform or elide any imports or exports not marked as type-only, ensuring they are written in the output file's format based on the 'module' setting. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,                         /* Disable resolving symlinks to their realpath. This correlates to the same flag in node. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            /* Ensure that casing is correct in imports. */

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,                                      /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                            /* Enable error reporting for expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,                         /* When type checking, take into account 'null' and 'undefined'. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,                      /* When assigning functions, check to ensure parameters and the return values are subtype-compatible. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,                      /* Check that the arguments for 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods match the original function. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,             /* Check for class properties that are declared but not set in the constructor. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when 'this' is given the type 'any'. */
    // "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,               /* Default catch clause variables as 'unknown' instead of 'any'. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                             /* Ensure 'use strict' is always emitted. */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                           /* Enable error reporting when local variables aren't read. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,                       /* Raise an error when a function parameter isn't read. */
    // "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,               /* Interpret optional property types as written, rather than adding 'undefined'. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,                        /* Enable error reporting for codepaths that do not explicitly return in a function. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,               /* Enable error reporting for fallthrough cases in switch statements. */
    // "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,                 /* Add 'undefined' to a type when accessed using an index. */
    // "noImplicitOverride": true,                       /* Ensure overriding members in derived classes are marked with an override modifier. */
    // "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,       /* Enforces using indexed accessors for keys declared using an indexed type. */
    // "allowUnusedLabels": true,                        /* Disable error reporting for unused labels. */
    // "allowUnreachableCode": true,                     /* Disable error reporting for unreachable code. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  }
}
```

###### Vscodeによるエラー画面

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

###### Typedoc Error

```
>npx typedoc script/Main.ts
script/FrameWork.ts:31:5 - error TS7034: Variable 'context' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.

31 let context = null;        //コンテキスト
       ~~~~~~~

script/FrameWork.ts:32:5 - error TS7034: Variable 'buffer' implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.

32 let buffer = null;        //バッファー
       ~~~~~~

script/FrameWork.ts:45:15 - error TS18047: 'canvas' is possibly 'null'.

45     context = canvas.getContext('webgl');             //webcontextコンテキストを作成
                 ~~~~~~

script/FrameWork.ts:45:22 - error TS2339: Property 'getContext' does not exist on type 'Element'.

45     context = canvas.getContext('webgl');             //webcontextコンテキストを作成
                        ~~~~~~~~~~

script/FrameWork.ts:191:17 - error TS7005: Variable 'context' implicitly has an 'any' type.

191     const buf = context.createBuffer();
                    ~~~~~~~
```

###### script.ts

```
import * as glm from "gl-matrix";


"use strict";

//モデルの情報
let model = 
{
    Translate:
    {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: -4,
    },

    Rotate:
    {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
    },

    Scale:
    {
        x: 1,
        y: 1,
        z: 1,
    },
};

//A
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let canvas;         //キャンバス
let context;        //コンテキスト
let buffer;        //バッファー
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let programInfo = {  attribLocations: {vertexPosition:null},uniformLocations: {projectionMatrix: null,position:null,scale:null,rotate:null},shaderProgram: null  };  //プログラム


//
// エントリーポイント
//
export function main() 
{


    canvas = document.querySelector('#glCanvas');     //キャンバスを取得
//B
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    context = canvas.getContext('webgl2');             //webcontextコンテキストを作成
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //webcontextコンテキストの作成に失敗した時
    if (!context) 
    {
        alert("webcontextコンテキストの作成失敗");
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // 頂点シェーダーコード
    const vsSource = `
    attribute vec4 aVertexPosition; //

    uniform mat4 uProjectionMatrix; //

    uniform mat4 uPosition; //
    uniform mat4 uScale;    //
    uniform mat4 uRotate;   //

    void main() {

        mat4 model = uPosition * uRotate * uScale;      //

        gl_Position = (uProjectionMatrix * model) * aVertexPosition;
    }

    `;

    // フラグメントシェーダー
    const fsSource = `
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
    `;

    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    //シェーダープログラムオブジェクトを作成
    const shaderProgram = CreateShaderProgram(vsSource,fsSource);//シェーダープログラムを作成

    programInfo.shaderProgram = shaderProgram;
    programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition = context.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram,'aVertexPosition');
    programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix = context.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,'uProjectionMatrix');

    programInfo.uniformLocations.position = context.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,'uPosition');
    programInfo.uniformLocations.scale = context.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,'uScale');
    programInfo.uniformLocations.rotate = context.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram,'uRotate');

    buffer = GetBuffer();  //バッファーを作成


    
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown",event => 
    {
        //スペースキー
        if(event.key == " ")
        {
            //alert("キーが押されました。");
            console.log("Space");
        }
        else if(event.key == "ArrowLeft")
        {
            //alert("キーが押されました。");
            console.log("Left");
 //           model.Translate.x += 10;
            model.Translate.x += -1.0 / 640.0;


            console.log(model.Translate.x);

        }
        else if(event.key == "ArrowRight")
        {
            //alert("キーが押されました。");
            console.log("Right");
            model.Translate.x += 1 / 640;

        }
        else if(event.key == "ArrowUp")
        {
            //alert("キーが押されました。");
            console.log("Up");
        }
        else if(event.key == "ArrowDown")
        {
            //alert("キーが押されました。");
            console.log("Down");
        }

    });




    // ######### 毎フレーム  #########

    
  //window.requestAnimationFrame(() =>{ Draw(); Update();   });

    function callback() 
    {
        Draw();
        Update();
        // ここに繰り返したい処理を書く。
        window.requestAnimationFrame(callback); // 毎回呼び出す必要あり。
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(callback); // 実行を開始。

}


//Update()
function Update()
{
  InputKey();
  

}

//Draw
function Draw()
{
    Render();
    //window.requestAnimationFrame(Draw);

}




//キー入力
function InputKey()
{


}



//バッファを初期化
function GetBuffer() 
{
    // 正方形の位置用のバッファを作成します。
    const buf = context.createBuffer();

    //バッファを適用
    context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER,buf);

    //正方形の頂点の配列
    const positions = 
    [
        1.0,1.0,0.0,
        -1.0,1.0,0.0,
        1.0,-1.0,0.0,
        -1.0,-1.0,0.0
    ];

    //バッファーオブジェクトのデータストアを初期化
    context.bufferData(context.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(positions),context.STATIC_DRAW);

    return buf;
  
}

//シーンを描画
function Render() 
{
    context.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // カラーバッファを初期化
    context.clearDepth(1.0);                 // 深度バッファを初期化
    context.enable(context.DEPTH_TEST);      // 深度テスト
    context.depthFunc(context.LEQUAL);       // 深度比較する値を設定

    //キャンバスに描画を開始する前に、キャンバスをクリア
    context.clear(context.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | context.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    //パースペクティブマトリックスを作成します
    const fieldOfView = 45 * Math.PI / 180;   // in radians
    const aspect = context.canvas.clientWidth / context.canvas.clientHeight;
    const zNear = 0.1;
    const zFar = 100.0;

    //射形行列
    const projectionMatrix = glm.mat4.create();
    glm.mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix,fieldOfView,aspect,zNear,zFar);

    //平行移動
    let translate = glm.mat4.create();
    glm.mat4.translate(translate,translate,[model.Translate.x,model.Translate.y,model.Translate.z]); 

    //回転
    let rotation = glm.mat4.create();
    glm.mat4.rotate(rotation,rotation,0,[model.Rotate.x,model.Rotate.y,model.Rotate.z]); 

    //拡大縮小
    let scale = glm.mat4.create();
    glm.mat4.scale(scale,scale,[model.Scale.x,model.Scale.y,model.Scale.z]); 

    context.bindBuffer(context.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);  //バッファーを適用

    context.vertexAttribPointer(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition,3,context.FLOAT,false,0,0);      //バッファーの頂点属性を統合
    context.enableVertexAttribArray(programInfo.attribLocations.vertexPosition);                            //バッファーの頂点属性を有効化

    //シェーダーを使う
    context.useProgram(programInfo.shaderProgram);

    // uniform 変数を設定
    context.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.projectionMatrix,false,projectionMatrix);
    context.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.position,false,translate);
    context.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.scale,false,scale);
    context.uniformMatrix4fv(programInfo.uniformLocations.rotate,false,rotation);

    context.drawArrays(context.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);  //描画

}

//シェーダーを作成
function CreateShaderProgram(vsSource,fsSource) 
{
    const vertexShader = LoadShader(context.VERTEX_SHADER, vsSource);
    const fragmentShader = LoadShader(context.FRAGMENT_SHADER, fsSource);

    //シェーダープログラムを作成
    const shaderProgram = context.createProgram();

    //アタッチ
    context.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    context.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    context.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

    // もしシェーダープログラムの作成に失敗したら
    if (!context.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, context.LINK_STATUS)) 
    {
        alert('シェーダープログラム作成に失敗:  ' + context.getProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram));

        return null;
    }

    return shaderProgram;
}

//シェーダーをロード
function LoadShader(type, source) 
{
    const shader = context.createShader(type);

    // ソースをシェーダーオブジェクトに送信します
    context.shaderSource(shader, source);

    // コンパイルシェーダー
    context.compileShader(shader);

    // コンパイルが成功したかどうか？
    if (!context.getShaderParameter(shader, context.COMPILE_STATUS)) 
    {
        alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + context.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        context.deleteShader(shader);

        return null;
    }

    return shader;
}

window.onload = main;  //実行
```

Comment: 「tsconfig.json」の内容も質問内に貼り付けてください。typedocは「tsconfig.json」に書かれた設定に基づきソースを解析するため、「tsconfig.json」の内容によって、動作が変わります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"tsconfig.json"で`strict`が真に設定されており、かつ、`noImplicitAny`が設定されていません。`strict`が真である場合で、個別に`noImplicitAny`を指定しない場合、`noImplicitAny`は真になります。`noImplicitAny`が真の場合は、[暗黙のany](https://typescriptbook.jp/reference/values-types-variables/any#%E6%9A%97%E9%BB%99%E3%81%AEany)が禁止されます。

質問のソースコードでは暗黙のanyが使用されています。そのため、`tsc`によるコンパイル※や`typedoc`によるドキュメント生成は、禁止されている暗黙のanyがあるため、エラーとなります。

※ `tsc hoge.ts`のようにファイル名のみをを指定した方法では、"tsconfig.json"を無視するため、コンパイルに成功する場合があります。

解決した場合は、質問で参考にしてしているドキュメントに従って暗黙のanyを使わないようにソースコードを修正するか、暗黙のanyを許可するように"tsconfig.json"を修正してください。